# Equation numbers in split environment messed up by ntheorem thref

Tags: numbering, amsmath, ntheorem

When I use `ntheorem` with the `thref` option, every time I use the `amsmath` `split` command the numbering skips ahead by one.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thref]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    a = b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    b = c
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        a & = b\\
        &= c
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The final equation should be numbered (3), but is instead numbered (4). Removing `thref` resolves the issue.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I usually advise against using `ntheorem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually advise against using `ntheorem`, but you may prefer it to `amsthm`. You can solve the problem of `thref` by *not* using the option and going to the much more powerful `cleveref` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{test}
\begin{equation}
    a = b
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\Cref{test} says something interesting.

\begin{equation}
    b = c
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        a & = b\\
        &= c
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Work-around: replace `split` with the `aligned` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thref]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    a = b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    b = c
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        a & = b\\
        &= c
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is that "work-around"?  (as it is, it sounds a bit dizzy.)

Comment: Thank you! It is interesting to me that this works, since `split` and `aligned` are both from amsmath and do similar things.

Comment: @Barbara Beeton: Maybe I meant ‘lol-around’ ;o)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thref]{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\forcefirstchoice{\firstchoice@false}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    a = b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    b = c
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\forcefirstchoice
    \begin{split}
        a & = b\\
        &= c
    \end{split}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}\forcefirstchoice
    \begin{split}
        a & = b\\
        &= c
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image: Blockquote]